# "for" inside list/Zip

Tags: python

In this code

```
    import random


    import numpy as np

    class Network(object):

        def __init__(self, sizes):
            """The list ``sizes`` contains the number of neurons in the
            respective layers of the network.  For example, if the list
            was [2, 3, 1] then it would be a three-layer network, with the
            first layer containing 2 neurons, the second layer 3 neurons,
            and the third layer 1 neuron.  The biases and weights for the
            network are initialized randomly, using a Gaussian
            distribution with mean 0, and variance 1.  Note that the first
            layer is assumed to be an input layer, and by convention we
            won't set any biases for those neurons, since biases are only
            ever used in computing the outputs from later layers."""
            self.num_layers = len(sizes)
            self.sizes = sizes
            self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
            self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                            for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

        def feedforward(self, a):
            """Return the output of the network if ``a`` is input."""
            for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
                a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
            return a

    NN=Network([3,2,1])
```

i dont understand :

1. **self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]**

if NN.sizes[1:] is [2,1]    then what is y??

2. the same for the next line

**self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]**

i dont understand either x nor how zip works here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, they are using list [comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/). The code

```
[np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
```

is the equivalent of

```
 self.biases=[]
 for y in sizes[1:]:
    self.biases.append(np.random.randn(y,1))
```

the line sizes[1:] is used to get the list values from the 1st index, i.e excluding the first element of the [list](https://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook009.html). For example,

```
a=[5,6,7,8]
print(a[1:])
```

gives output as `[6,7,8]`
Also, if you give `print(a[:-1])` we will get output as `[5,6,7]`

Now, for the next line,

```
self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

the equivalent code using for loops is

```
self.weights=[]
for (x,y) in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:]):
    self.weights.append(n.random.randn(y,x))
```

[Zip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/) is nothing but maps the two lists and allows you to traverse through both the lists at the same time. In this case, sizes[:-1], list sizes excluding the last element and sizes[1:], list sizes excluding the first element.
For example, If you have two lists and you need to print both of them as follows:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=['a','b','c','d']
p=list(zip(a,b))
print (p)
```

will give you

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

Now if you have to print each element:

```
for k,v in zip(a,b):
    print (k,v)
```

Will give you output as

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Hope you are clear!

Comment: Can i ask something more??
in the line


self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

if size is [2,3,1] then x=(2,3) and y=(3,1)...Correct??
then what are the dimensions of self.weights??
is it a list of 2 matrices??

Comment: if size is [2,3,1] , then zip(size[1:],size[1:]) will be [(3,2),(1,3)]. So in the first iteration, x=3,y=1, value appended to self.weights=np.random.randn(1,3) , second iteration x=2,y=3, value appended to self.weights=np.random.randn(3,2) . self.weights will be a list of numpy arrays. Each array will have the dimension (y,x) . i.e in this case  self.weights contains two numpy arrays with dimensions (1,3) and (3,2).

Comment: sorry a im new here,dont know the ''rules'' :)